# Bind (DNS) configuration is showing no error and still `dig` is not showing any DNS record (for SPF)

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, email-server, bind

I have killed my few days trying to fix this issue but I cannot figure out anything to solve this.
So I have a VPS and it has Webuzo panel installed in it. I added few domains and also added the `SPF`, `DMARC` ... etc so that my emails can work properly. The Webuzo panel was showing everything done, but when I test it with external website it shows that there is no SPF record for my domain.

I used the command `dig` on my server to test the domain, and I get following output:

```
[root@hit named]# dig -t txt example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-74.el7_6.1 <<>> -t txt example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28691
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.    IN      TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com. 1799       IN SOA  cdns1.hosting_provider.net. dns.hosting_provider.net. 2018052001 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 85 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 06 16:07:51 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 108

[root@hit named]#
```

When I applied same on say `google.com`, it clearly gives SPF record there.

Webuzo uses `bind` (`named`) for DNS Zone settings. I have tried the `named-checkzone` command and it shows no error.

The configuration in `bind` and `example.com`'s zone are both created by the panel `Webuzo`. The configuration of `named.conf` is very basic and I see no issue in it (I can put here if you need). Also the configuration for `example.com` is as follows:

```
$TTL 14400
@      86400    IN      SOA    cdns1.hosting-provider.net. admin.hit.example.net. (
     2019070602 ; serial, todays date+todays
     86400       ; refresh, seconds
     7200        ; retry, seconds
     3600000     ; expire, seconds
     86400 ); minimum, seconds

example.com. IN NS cdns1.hosting-provider.net.
example.com. IN NS cdns2.hosting-provider.net.

;Zone Contents
example.com. 14400 IN A 201.73.201.68
cdns1 14400 IN A 208.73.201.68
cdns2 14400 IN A 208.73.201.68
localhost.example.com. 14400 IN A 127.0.0.1
example.com. 14400 IN MX 0 example.com.    
www 14400 IN CNAME example.com.    
ftp 14400 IN A 208.11.11.101    
@ 14400 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:208.11.11.101 ~all"   
_dmarc 14400 IN TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none;"
```

The only reason I am thinking that the configuration should be "okay" is because they are auto generated by Webuzo. The files are linked properly with `named.conf` and they pass the checks by `named-checkconf` and `named-checkzone`. And I have no idea why there is no SPF record being shown anywhere!

I know I might be missing something simple, and if this question is already answered then please refer it! I am really frustrated with this as I cannot just figure it out!

Please ask for any clarification if required.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error; `1y4400` is not a valid TTL. Remove `y`, update serial and `rndc reload`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer! I will check it soon. But still I am wondering how Webuzo is creating invalid config and why `named-checkzone` isn't throwing error! Still I hope you are right and this gets sorted!

Comment: I am so sorry but it was my mistake while copying I guess... the configuration had 14400 and it is not working! I have fixed the question. Can you please suggest me something... should I use PowerDNS?

Answer (score 0):

The VPS provider had a separate DNS manager running outside the OS of VPS! And that's why no change on DNS config whatsoever was visible on the internet. I found the DNS panel on the VPS management page on the web hosting provider's dashboard, and simply added the records!

(Yes, it was dumb of me!)